# R Set Spatial Points in a Matrix around given Spatial Points

Tags: qgis, raster, r, spatial-analysis

I am struggling  with the task to set one point in each pixel (of a given raster) in a distance of 3km of my points.

I tried buffering in QGIS and R but cannot find a way to set exactly one point in each pixel.
I think it will work with creating a matrix around the points but I couldn´t find a way doing this.

Data:
46 species presence points;
Raster Stack with environmental Data Res: 100x100m

[image]

raster with presence points (zoomed in)

[image: Crosses: pts; false buffers in purple]

presence points: black crosses, buffers(false): purple, backgroundraster: allbands

[image]

gridpts

code:

```
# Points in Matrix around Presence Data 

# #---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Prework

# Packs 
library(spdep)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(RStoolbox)
library(rgdal)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Data 

# Presence Points: 
pts <-readOGR("D://GIDEON_korrigiert_aktuell_repro_EPSG32648_forR.shp")

> pts
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 46 
extent      : -507313, 812849.9, 761011.2, 2831574  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=utm +zone=48 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 2
names       :    Lat,     Lon 
min values  : 10,230, 100,030 
max values  :  7,880,  99,950 

# Raster: 
allbands <- raster("D:/Database/AllReproCliped_for_DOWN/ForestFrek/Stack_8er_Prec_Wet_Temp_Land_Tree_Short_Bare_ForestFrek.tif")

> allbands
class      : RasterLayer 
band       : 1  (of  8  bands)
dimensions : 23913, 17032, 407286216  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 106.8938, 106.8938  (x, y)
extent     : -835901.2, 984713.7, 624198, 3180349  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=48 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : D:/Chris/Studium/BA/QGIS_Datein/Database/AllReproCliped_for_DOWN/ForestFrek/Stack_8er_Prec_Wet_Temp_Land_Tree_Short_Bare_ForestFrek.tif 
names      : Stack_8er_Prec_Wet_Temp_Land_Tree_Short_Bare_ForestFrek 
values     : -6.3375, 28.77083  (min, max)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Plot 

plot(allbands)
plot(pts, add= TRUE)
```

[image]

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Buffer 

pres_st <- st_as_sf(pts, crs= "bogus")
crs(pres_st)

d = 3000 
buf <- st_buffer(pres_st, dist=d)

gridpts <- st_as_sf(
  as.data.frame(
    mask(allbands, buf),
    xy=TRUE,
    na.rm=TRUE),
  coords=1:2,
  crs=st_crs(allbands))

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Plot

plot(gridpts)
```

[image]

```
plot(allbands)
plot(pts, add=TRUE)
plot(gridpts, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I can't quite understand what your expected output is. Your input is 46 points and a raster. Is your output a set of points? 46 of them? Or do you want a point for every pixel in your raster? Across the whole of your raster, or only the non-missing area (land?)?

Comment: My expected output is a layer with spatial points around my existing presence points.

Comment: Try Raster Sampling in the Toolbox. It samples the raster at the vector locations.

Comment: What **precisely** do you mean "around"? How close? How many "around" each point? Where does the raster come into this?

Comment: I wanted so set one point in each pixel in a distance of 3km of my points. The Raster is stacked environmental data (Landcover etc.)

Comment: Where in each pixel do you want the points? In the centre of the pixels? Randomly in the pixel somewhere? Is this for pixels that are fully within 3km, or partially? You say your resolution is 100mx100m, but how big is your raster?

Comment: In the centre of the pixels would be great. Also the ones that partially would be nice but isn´t that important.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. Code in comments is barely legible to illegible, depending on the language.

Comment: That looks like it has not picked up the X and Y coordinates from the `as.data.frame` conversion of the raster. Try `coords=c("x","y")` instead of `coords=1:2`?

Comment: Indeed this was the problem. I played around and found that ```coords=2:3``` workes perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a dem and some points:

```
> plot(dem)
> plot(pts, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

I'll make a 1km buffer for my data:

```
> d = 1000
> buf = st_buffer(pts, dist=d)
```

Then I can get all the grid points in the buffer by masking the DEM to the buffer and taking all the coordinates of non-NA pixels and making an `sf` points data frame out of them:

```
> gridpts = st_as_sf(
      as.data.frame(
        mask(dem,buf),
        xy=TRUE,
        na.rm=TRUE),
      coords=1:2,
      crs=st_crs(dem))
```

which looks like this:

[image]

which is actually nearly 3000 points so close together you can't tell them apart.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you very much for that. Unfortunately it does not work with my data. I have updated the post so you can see the problem. When I plot the points by themselves, they are all in line with each other and not near my presence points.I have tried data conversion but could not find a solution.

Comment: If my answer *doesnt work* then why have you ticked it as an accepted answer? I still can't see the problem even after your edit. What points are "all in a line with each other"? I don't see points in a line on your question.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that! I have updated the post to make it clearer.

Comment: Its not clearer unless you include the code you used! From your edits I see you have a SpatialPointsDataFrame which will not work with my code because I'm using the `sf` package, and functions like `st_buffer` will not work with that. Show your working in your question alongside the summary outputs of your data objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with `terra`

Example data

```
library(terra)
#terra version 1.2.5
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
set.seed(1234)
pts <- spatSample(r, 2, xy=TRUE, values=FALSE, as.points=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Solution:

```
b <- buffer(pts, 5000)
cnrs <- cells(r, b)
xy <- xyFromCell(r, cnrs[,2])

plot(r)
points(xy)
lines(b, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution with the exact same data but got the error: Error in .local(x, ...) : 
  not used argument (values = FALSE, as.points = TRUE)      when running pts <- ....    // terra version: terra_1.1-17

Comment: You need current terra (version 1.2-5)